# 1024 bit key generation in php

Tags: php, random, cryptography

I want to use this function to store 1024 bit keys in my Mysql database. If you call generateKey(128), you'll get a 128 byte string, same as 1024 bit string. I want to know if there is something wrong with this code or if I should be worried about inter-operability issues with MySQL, Java, Android, File Read/Write, etc.

```
    public function generateKey($size){

    $randomString = "";
    $charUniverse = "";
    for($i=0;$i<256;$i++){
        $charUniverse .= chr($i);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
        $randInt=mt_rand(0, strlen($charUniverse)-1);
        $randChar=$charUniverse[$randInt];
        $randomString=$randomString.$randChar;
    }
    return $randomString;     
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `chr($randInt)` instead of `$charUniverse[$randInt]`, and abandon the `$charUniverse` variable altogether.
- Use the `$str .= "str"` dot-equals operator in PHP to append to your final string.

Thus your code becomes:

```
public function generateKey($size){
 
   $randomString = "";
   $charDomainSize = 256;
   for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
     $randInt=mt_rand(0, $charDomainSize-1);
     $randChar=chr($randInt);
     $randomString .= $randChar;
   }
   return $randomString; 
        
}
```

If we compress your code further, it becomes:

```
public function generateKey($size){
   $randomString = "";
   for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
      $randomString .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
   }
   return $randomString;
}
```

I conducted a speed test, as well. The new code is faster (1000 runs, varied sizes between 1128 and 1148). The units are seconds.

- Function 1 Average: 0.024438648223877
- Function 2 Average: 0.015253195762634

Only using 256 as a size, 1000 runs:

- Function 1 Average: 0.00031177306175232
- Function 2 Average: 0.00017282342910767

This is a little overkill, but I was bored.

It should be very easy to port your random string generator to other platforms, although it may develop more or less dependable randomness based on the underlying generators. E.g. don't use Java's java.util.Random for security or scientific purposes (see [Difference between java.util.Random and java.security.SecureRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051205/difference-between-java-util-random-and-java-security-securerandom)).

You might also want to consider PHP's [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php), depending on your intent. That may not be as easily ported, though, as your current code.

Answer (score 1):

FROM Php manual
Caution

This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

Comment: Another answer already mentioned `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. This answer doesn't seem to add value.